# Google Analytics: In view setting, does choosing http or https impact the data?

Tags: google-analytics

About 1 month ago, I added SSL to my Joomla website and forced all http to https in its setting. But I forgot to change the setting in my Goolge Analytics view setting.

[image]

Will this impact my data?

I am asking this because I am seeing some huge differences between the pageview recorded by Google analytics and the hit count on my site. Mine is a small site and the average hit count is like 2.5k. Usually the pageview on GA is 10-20% lower. But for the past month I've seen an article with 3k hit count while GA pageview is only 800+. Trying to find out why and wondering whether the https/http could be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

GA is protocol agnostic, however for consistency and to avoid confusion, I would ensure the settings reflect what protocol the website currently is, and make an annotation in the GA interface as to the date the site changed to SSL, and what date the GA settings were changed.

As for seeing why there may be large differences in traffic, check back against the previous month to see if you have lost traffic from any main referrers, drops in traffic from particular browser/devices, traffic from varying countries.

Have you checked previous GA traffic for integrity, to see if maybe a portion of it was spam data that is now no longer being reported?